# got ANR on clicking button in my App (Android)

Tags: android

i have a button in my app, if i click it once, everything is OK, the problem is when i keep clicking it very quickly, i'll get an ANR. Here is part of my code:

```
shareBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            shareBtn.setClickable(false);
            new UploadPicture().execute(urls);                    
        }
    });

private class UploadPicture extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
         protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {

            Booblean boo = uploadPic(picPath);  

            return boo;
         }

         protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
             //do nothing
         }
     }
```

1, i have shareBtn.setClickable(false);
2, i use AsyncTask to do things that will cost long time.

anyone could give me some advices? Thanks a lot!

Comment: i'dont need to enable it again. and i've tried that too, i even have tried shareBtn.setOnClickListener(null); but nothing works.

Comment: can you let us know two things 1- what is picPath 2 - provide uploadPic function............

Comment: Concider posting full source code.that would help to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is a problem with pre android 4.0 version**

If you click the button rapidly.it queues all clicks and process them one by one.
but what you want is after first click ignore rest of the clicks.

Edit your code as follows

```
boolean isClickable=true;
shareBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(isClickable)
             { 
            new UploadPicture().execute(urls);                    
             }
           isClickable=false;
        }
    });

private class UploadPicture extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
         protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {

            Booblean boo = uploadPic(picPath);  

            return boo;
         }

         protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
             //do nothing
         }
     }
```

Comment: You will need to figure out when to reset `isClickable` to `true`. I assume you can do this once the upload has completed.

Comment: Yes it just contains snapshot of what could should look like.he will have to reset it.